# Does 寒気がする really mean "have a chill" or is it just cold?

Tags: meaning

Can the expression:

寒気{さむけ}が   する

really mean feel cold and also have a chill (as per many dictionaries)?

To me, to have a chill/bug means to be sick from a virus/cold for a short period: have I missed something?

For reference I give the followings nouns fitting the construction "がする”・to sense:

> におい、音、気、味
>   [smell, sound, feel, taste]

Comment: We also often say 寒気がする when we hear ghost stories and feel scared. cf. ぞっとする, ぞぞぞ, ぞーっ

Comment: @Chocolate:  I didn't know that - thanks!

Comment: So "have a chill" = "spine-tingling" in that sense.  I wonder how many dictionaries have that as part of the definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are sick (especially when you have a fever), you sometimes feel the cold as if it were colder than it actually is.  [[寒気]{さむけ}](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E3%81%95%E3%82%80%E3%81%91) means this feeling of coldness.  It does not matter whether it is caused by viruses or bacteria, nor does it matter whether it is for a short period or for a long period.  As Chocolate noted, it also means the similar feeling caused by fear.  The word “chill” in English has a similar meaning.

(Do not confuse with a separate word [[寒気]{かんき}](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%AF%92%E6%B0%97&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&pagenum=1&index=107837700000), which is written in the same way in kanji.)

Comment: Does `寒気（さむけ）` overlap with `悪寒` then?  Although I don't think `悪寒` implies having a fever/cold, does it?

Comment: @istrasci: (1) Yes, 寒気 (さむけ) and 悪寒 are quite similar.  In fact, 悪寒 implies being sick more strongly than 寒気 because I think that 悪寒 is limited to the feeling of coldness arising from being sick and not the one arising from fear.  (2) I changed the wording in the answer a little, because one can feel 寒気 (and 悪寒 for that matter) from sickness even when one does not actually have a fever (high body temperature).  In this sense, feeling 寒気 or 悪寒 does not logically imply having a fever.

Comment: What would you say to convey having non-illness chills?  I am a 寒がり, so there are some winter mornings where I'm not sick and I just cannot get warm.  I've used 悪寒 before (今朝はずっと悪寒！), but from what you said, this wasn't correct because I wasn't sick.

Comment: @istrasci: I personally think that it is incorrect to use the word 悪寒 in that situation.  If someone says 悪寒がする, I definitely think that he/she feels sick and not that he/she feels the cold easily.  (But other people may have different opinions…let’s wait for other people to chime in!)

Comment: @istrasci: As an aside, omitting がする in 悪寒がする does not sound correct to me, even in a casual conversation.

Comment: @istrasci: I forgot to reply to this part: “What would you say to convey having non-illness chills?”  I would say something along “寒い,” “寒く感じる,” “すうすうする,” and “すこすこする.”  The last one might be dialectal (I am not sure).