# Usage of する for the five senses - 音がする, 匂いがする, etc

Tags: meaning

Do these type of expressions mean that something is being perceived or that something is producing said sound/smell/etc?

For example, in the Weblio website I saw "門を叩く音がする" translated as "There is a knock at the door". But "足音がする" is translated as "I hear footsteps."

So does "音がする" mean "(I) hear a sound" or "There is a sound/(Something) makes a sound"?

Comment: You wrote "the five senses", but ～がする is used for *non-visual* sensory perception.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27545/をする-and-がする-meanings-and-uses

Comment: Related: [「〜がする」 the extended use of する (to do)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17850/%e3%81%8c%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-the-extended-use-of-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-to-do) See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2289/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9816/9831